# Moodle changes password hash on its own

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I try to implement short-term-password functionality in the default/manual moodle auth plugin.

Therefor I have a table containing the `user_id`, `password` hashed by `hash_internal_user_password` and a `valid_from` as well as a `valid_to` timestamp.

Inside the `user_login($username, $password)` method of the auth plugin I added the following block

```
    // Test for short-term-passwords
    $stps = $DB->get_records('local_stp', ['user_id' => $user->id]);
    foreach ($stps as $stp ) {
        $now = time();
        $validFrom = (int) $stp->valid_from;
        $validTo = (int) $stp->valid_to;

        if ($now < $validFrom || $now > $validTo) {
            continue;
        }

        if (password_verify($password, $stp->password)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This works like charm. But every time I login in with one of these temporary passwords the hash of the default user password changes and I can't login using the regular password.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located in the `update_internal_user_password` function defined in `lib/moodlelib.php`. Whenever moodle gets access to a clear text password it updates the related database record. This behavior cant be blocked.